# On Ghostscript: Fastest way to create a blank .tif document

Tags: image-processing, tiff, ghostscript

A legacy backend requires the email body with a .tif document, no tif and it fails. So i need to generate a blank .tif, is there a fast way to do this with ghostscript?

---

edit: make once in project installation use when i need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line will produce a 1 pixel Tiff file (340 bytes). That's the smallest Tiff file I could get.

```
gswin32c.exe -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffpack -g1x1 -sOutputFile=small.tif -c newpath 0 0 moveto 1 1 lineto closepath stroke showpage quit
```

Actually, you can even reduce the command to:

```
gswin32c.exe -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffpack -g1x1 -sOutputFile=small.tif -c showpage quit
```

without size gain, alas.

Comment: Even shorter:
 `gswin32c -o small.tif -g1x1 -sDEVICE=tiffpack -c showpage quit`. Result is 302 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you make your blank .tif file once and then attach the same file every time it is needed?

Comment: It is better to do this, but I still would like to generate it, as I would prefer not to create it then distribute it in the package.

Comment: The definition of .tif isn't going to change so the once generated file could be thought of as just a set of bytes that is the magic word for "blank .tif".  You don't have to store that in the file system, it could be as a resource or directly in code.  Isn't that better than an extra dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Might be something here: [Re: [R] Making TIFF images with rtiff](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e2/help/07/01/8435.html)